# SEO optimisation for a video-heavy website

Tags: seo, google-search, optimization

I am creating a website which will have much more videos than actual text. Now this concerns me as I want the particular site which I can not reveal details about here, to rank within the top 3 on google search engine.

For example purposes, let's say that my website is for providing users with videos of skateboarding. There will be around 20 videos of people skateboarding in skate parks.

Now for the whole style of the website, in design content isn't looking right. I have designed the pages with correct H1 ,H2 ,H3 ,H4 tags. For example:

```
<h1>Skateboarding Videos</h1>
```

Then a row of 4 videos, these videos will have random names which may not have the words skateboarding, as it would look silly if all the videos had near the same name.

```
<h2>Watch out best moments in skateboarding</h2>
```

then another row of 4 videos.

Now in two columns would be something like

```
<h3>The users voted best skateboarding clip</h3>
```

Then one big video.

```
<h3>Check out your nearest skateboarding parks now</h3>
```

Then a few links to near places.

```
<h4>Skateboarding products we suggest</h4>
```

almost like an amazon style of listed products in a row.

So this is not a real website as I can't disclose the idea, however as you can see it will be mostly made up of h tags, very small chunks of paragraph tags, and a lot of video content.

I am a bit of an SEO freak and using Yoast's SEO tool I normally have all of my pages green (passed on everything). However, I know this will not be achievable here.

What would you guys suggest for me to do in this situation/example to bring as much traffic as possible for the search terms like skateboarding videos, skateboarding clips, skateboarding in UK etc... you get the jist.

Comment: Let's start with Yoast Video SEO plugin which allow google to index your videos, and end up in the google developer center when they suggest you to have at least 300 words on every page of your website, 300 words is nothing if you can get into this 300 words and take a look at the yoast seo plugin for videos you can still be OK. I can't give longer answer at this time but I will try whenever I'm free to give you more information. https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/video-seo/

Comment: This will not be a WordPress site, its going to be built with laravel framework as it requires to be much more robust. SO Yoast's SEO plugin is out of the question. Also the videos will be of am adult nature meaning they probably wont be on google videos

Comment: I see I assumed you are going to use wordpress as you mentioned yoast seo plugin.

Comment: Sorry to confuse you, just image this is a website coded in pure html and css.

Comment: What you've described sounds like a video category page. Does each video also have its own page?

Comment: yes GDAv it does

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few other suggestions...

1) To help with indexing of pages and video in Google, check out the video XML sitemap. https://developers.google.com/webmasters/videosearch/sitemaps You said in a comment that this was a straight up html/css site, so check out tools that can build this dynamically (without a CMS like WordPress), for example: https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/video-sitemap.html

2) Thin content pages like you are describing can and do rank in Google, so if this content is enough for your users I'd leave it. However, on the balance, more useful content tends to be better when trying for competitive rankings. So, what other content can you include on the page that would be useful? What about comments or transcripts? For products or nearby places you are mentioning, what additional content can you add here--even if it is a 10-15 word blurb vs. a sentence or paragraph that could help to add context.

3) Also, remember that a large chunk of what causes sites to rank highly has nothing to do with the content of your page. Building links (quality links) are a large part of off page factors, but so is (directly or indirectly) social media, reviews on other websites, PR, affiliate relationships (if appropriate), events/webinars/etc. and any offline marketing you are doing. When I've worked on sites with limited content, by focusing on these factors you can still gain higher rankings. In your case, you may want to invest more time on these factors vs. coming up with yet more content.